# Using prepareForSegue to send an image file name from one ViewController to the next

Tags: ios, swift, segue, viewcontroller

I'm trying to send the image data from one view controller to the other.  The data is hard coded in a separate swift file. I have a data file in xcode which contains the following:

```
class Data {

struct Entry {

    let filename: String
    let heading: String
    let headerSub: String

    init(profilePicture: String, profileTitle: String, profileSub: String) {
        self.heading = profileTitle
        self.filename = profilePicture
        self.headerSub = profileSub
    }

}

let headerData = [

    Entry(profilePicture: "image1.png", profileTitle: "person1", profileSub: ""),
    Entry(profilePicture: "image2.png", profileTitle: "person2", profileSub: ""),
]

}
```

And, in my ViewController, I have the following:

```
let categorySegueIdentifier = "CategoryDetailSegue"

   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == categorySegueIdentifier {
            if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? RequestViewController {
                if let categoryIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {
                destination.categoryImage.image = data[0]

            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the beginning of the ViewController, I have added the following -

```
let data = Data()
```

In my destination view controller I have the following -

```
var categoryImage = UIImage()

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    headerImage.image = categoryImage
}
```

Why am I getting the following error:
UIImage does not have a member named image

Any idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

```
destination.categoryImage = data[0]
```

not this:

```
destination.categoryImage.image = data[0]
```

That is assuming that `data[0]` is a `UIImage`.  If it's a file name, you'll of course want to do this:

```
if let image = UIImage( named:data[0] ) {
    destination.categoryImage = image
}
```